# Memory usage due to pickle/joblib

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, pickle, joblib

I have a significant large dataset consisting of several thousands of files spread among different directories. These files all have different formats and come from different sensors giving me different sampling rates. Basically, a mess. I created a python module that is able to enter these folders and make sense of all this data, reformat it, get it into a `pandas` dataframe that I could use for effective and easy resampling, and in general, make it easier to work with.

The problem is that the resulting dataframe is big and takes a large amount of RAM memory. Loading several of these datasets leaves not enough memory available to actually train a ML model. And it is painfully slow to read the data.

So my solution is a two part approach. First, I read the dataset into a big variable. It is a `dict` with nested pandas `DataFrame`, then compute a reduced derived `DataFrame` with the information I actually need to train my model, and remove from memory the `dict` variable. Not ideal, but it works. However, further computations sometimes needs re-reading the data and as stated previously, it is slow.

Enter the second part. Before removing the `dict` from memory, I pickle it into a file. `sklearn` actually recommends using `joblib`, so that's what I use. So, once the single files for the dataset are stored in the working directory, the reading stage is about 90% faster than reading the scattered data, most likely because is loading a single large file directly into memory than reading and reformatting thousands of files across different directories.

Here's my problem. The same code when is reading the data from the scattered files, ends up with about 70% less RAM than when reading the pickled data. So, although it is faster, it ends up using much memory. Has anybody experienced something like this?

Given that there are some access issues to the data (it is located in a network drive with some weird restrictions for user access) and the fact that I need to make it as user friendly as possible for other people, I'm using a Jupyter notebook. My IT department provides a web tool with all the packages required to read the network drive from the go and run Jupyter there, whilst running from a VM will require the manual configuration of the network drive to access the data and that part is not user friendly. The Jupyter tool requires only login information, while the VM requires a basic knowledge of linux sysadmin

I'm using Python 3.9.6. I'll keep trying to get a MWE that has a similar situation. So far I have one that has the opposite behaviour (loading the pickled dataset consumes less memory than reading it directly). Might be because the particular structure of the `dict` with nested `DataFrame`

MWE (Warning, running this code will create a 4GB file in your hard drive):

```
import numpy as np
import psutil
from os.path import exists
from os import getpid
from joblib import dump, load

## WARNING. THIS CODE SAVES A LARGE FILE INTO YOUR HARD DRIVE
def read_compute():
    if exists('df.joblib'):
        df = load('df.joblib')
        print('==== df loaded from .joblib')
    else:
        df = np.random.rand(1000000,500)
        dump(df, 'df.joblib')
        print('=== df created and dumped')
    tab = df[:100, :10]
    del df
    return tab

table = read_compute()
print(f'{psutil.Process(getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2} MB')
```

With this, I get when running without the `df.joblib` file in the pwd

```
=== df created and dumped
3899.62890625 MB
```

And then, after that file is created, I restart the kernel and run the same code again, getting

```
==== df loaded from .joblib
1588.5234375 MB
```

In my actual case, with the format of my data, I have the opposite effect.

Comment: Have you considered to store your data into a database and only use the part you need when performing analysis task. I have the feeling that it might solve your problem.

Comment: How would that work? Which format or library?. My raw data is scattered in thousands of files. I read them and put them into my data structure: a ´dict´ where the key identifies a test condition. And within each key there is a list where every element is a different pandas ´DataFrame´. I though it was possible to put everything within a pandas ´DataFrame´, but it was tricky to deal with different sampling frequencies in the raw data (I have 1 Hz, 60 Hz, 400 Hz and 1000 Hz). So the data I'm pickling is the ´dict´. The ´DataFrame´ are kinda like databases, I guess, so maybe I need to revisit it

Comment: Data frames are not database. They are very different things, even if they both looks like rectangular tables. Database will help you to standardise the information and store it properly for good on disk. Then you will be able to query only parts you need to work on and load it into frames which may lower your RAM footprint.